# How to deploy a website via git pull?

Tags: git, github, deployment, web-deployment

I am planning to use GitHub to manage the code for my next website. Although I have used GitHub in the past, I have never used it to deploy a website. My rather unsophisticated plan is as follows:

[image]

However, I have several concerns about this model:

1. If I am using `git pull` on my remote server, does that mean my website directory itself will become a git repository? If so, is there a way I can avoid this? For instance, could I create a `/var/repo` directory to contain the git repository and then "copy" the code over to the actual website directory (`/var/www`)? Is there an efficient way to set this up?
2. Let's assume I run `git pull` for the first time and deploy the website on my server. Next, let's assume I *edit* an existing file and *add* a file directly on the server via FTP. When I run `git pull` for the second time, how will git handle these two files? Will my edited file be replaced and my new file be deleted? Will my edited file be replaced and my new file untouched? Will I not be able to run git pull at all?
3. Let's assume I have a file named `config.php` on my computer that contains the usernames/passwords for the various users that can access my databases. Since `config.php` on my computer is configured for my localhost environment, when I use `git pull` on my server for the first time I will have to edit the variables. As such, when I run `git pull` for the second time, is that file on my server replaced with the localhost version again?
4. As a followup to the last question: what would be the best way to handle configuration files that contain data such as usernames and passwords? Not only do I want to hide this sensitive data from the public GitHub repository, but I also want to ensure that when I run `git pull`, the already-modified configuration files on my server remain untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can not run `git pull` without being in a git repo so first time you have to do a `git clone repo_url` to get the code to remote server. If you don't want to keep `.git` in `var/www` i.e. your git repo so you can pull the code to some other directory then move the code using `rsync` or `mv`.
2. Editing files directly on remote server in considered a bad practice and it can bring conflicts to your repo. Anyway if you edit directly on remote server you won't be able to pull from github because git will throw an error saying `your local changes will be overwritten with this merge`. So you have to either stash the changes or drop them completely.
3. For files containing passwords and other things i would suggest use environment variables for both local and remote server. Use environment variables in config.php to get sensitive information from the system. You just have to set those environment variables in the remote server once
4. If you have any sensitive data then just put those files in `.gitignore`. When you pull your code from github, any file in gitignore will remain untouched as git will ignore those files.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, it will. But, if you specify in your `.htaccess`(or equivalent file) that the `.git` folder is to not be served, it shouldn't make much of a difference to end users.
2. If you are going to have the server `git pull` then you don't want to directly modify the content on the server. If you do, you would have to commit your changes on the server and then merge them with your local changes. This will become messy. So, just always modify on your local machine, and push and pull accordingly.
3. You should **never** store passwords in plain text, especially in a public GitHub repo. Have a completely separate part of the server (that is not under git) that stores the usernames/passwords *hashed and salted*. You can FTP to this location separately. You could also have 2 separate files, one for local development and one for the server.
4. I kinda already answered this, just make sure to store the usernames / passwords somewhere else.

Comment: How is his application to authenticate itself on a database server if those credentials are hashed and salted?